# .htacess route url1 to url2 without changing the browser url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Having issue achieving the results with wordpress now would like to do this using htacess would like to make the url

`http://example.com/blog-preview/$any` accessable by `http://example.com/blog/$any`

without changing the browser url i:e `http://example.com/blog/$any`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this using the htaccess-file. The reason being, that the htaccess-file can just redirect stuff around, - but if can't move content from one page to another, which is what it sounds like that you're after.

I would do this, by making a function and putting that in `functions.php`, and then using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), to get the content from the page that needs to be displayed.

### Solution 1: Standardize it for all pages:

```
function custom20190126_preview_function() {

  $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $target_uri = '/blog/';
  if( substr( $request_uri, 0, strlen( $target_uri ) === $target_uri ){
    echo file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/blog-preview/foobar' );
    die();
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom20190126_preview_function' );
```

### Solution 2: Get the content from a specific page-template

If you want to do it from a page-template in WordPress, then you could make a function and call it from from your page-template (like `single.php` or `archive.php`). Like so:

**In archive.php**

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( 'https://example.com/blog-preview/foobar' );
?>
```